# Excel 2010 Macro Pivot Label Filter

Tags: vba, excel, filter, pivot

I am having an issue running a label filter on a column (classic view) within my pivot table. I am trying to weed out the items in the data that are less than 180 days old. I can't adjust the data because it is used to feed multiple worksheets and I don't wish to copy the data and manipulate it for just this worksheet. Below is the line that I am running.

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("Ageing").PivotFilters.Add _
        Type:=xlCaptionIsBetween, Value1:="180", Value2:="9999"
```

This is a "between" filter. I have tried greater than and greater than or equal to but the same result occurs. After this line is run, I can click into the pivot table soft/filter down arrow and see that the filter is there as a between and even the days are inputted but the data does not reflect this. If I hit "OK" on the filter it then applies itself but I do not wish to have to do this manually.

Yes, "PivotTable5" is the pivot table in question. Can anyone help me automate this process?

Comment: can you show your `PivotTable5` ? it's hard to understand the structure of your data, also how are the values inside ? Numeric ? dates? String ?

Comment: Did you clear all filters before invoking the .Add method? Did you try the .Add2 method? Why are your values strings? You have provided little info.

Comment: The values of aging are numbers from 1 to 1,000+ but the format is "General". did clear all filters before hand using the line below.

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").ClearAllFilters

I am not sure what you mean by .add2 or strings. Can you please clarify? I apologize as I use macros often but the range I cover is very small. Thanks for the help in advance guys!

Comment: @OldUgly Can you give me an example of the .add2 method? The values are a between X and Y as those are points in which I want the data to show.

Comment: @ShaiRado it is for work so unfortunately I can't share the data but I can describe it. They are listed from 1 to 1.000+ in numeric format.